# Perl: How can i test for a URL ( https ) accepting GET requests using "login" parameter

Tags: perl, security, http

I have a CGI server side script that accepts GET and POST, with login parameters.
I want to test it to make sure it is not vulnerable. So the plan is to use Perl LWP, and send login parameters in GET and POST, and compare the results. the interface has been changed, so that only in POST we can send user-name and password in session cookies ( not sure if that is a great idea ) , so how do i test it ? Here is what i have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP;
print "This is libwww-perl-$LWP::VERSION\n";
# Create a user agent object
  use LWP::UserAgent;
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  $ua->agent("MyApp/0.1 ");

  # Create a request
  #my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => 'http://search.cpan.org/search');
  #my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'https://qa.co.net:443/cgi-bin/n-cu.cgi');
  my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'https://qa.co.net:443/cgi-bin/n-cu.cgi?mode=frameset&JScript=1&remote_user&login=foo&password=foo HTTP/1.1');
  $req->content_type('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  $req->content('query=libwww-perl&mode=dist');
  # Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
  my $res = $ua->request($req);

  # Check the outcome of the response
  if ($res->is_success) {
      print $res->content;
      #print $res->code;
      #print $res->message;
  }
  else {
      print $res->status_line, "\n";
  }
```

This is not going to do it, since it does not have the session cookie stuff. But might be a good start though. Is this the right way to test the GET and POST ?

Here is what was implemented in the cgi:

```
#cr_login for POST && login for GET -- leave GET param as it used to be.
     if ($m eq 'GET' && defined($req->param('login'))) {
         $msg = 'parameter "login" is invalid for this request type.';
+        my $seclog = $event_logging_directory . '/invalid_request.log';
+        open(S, ">>$seclog") or die $!;
+        my $logmsg = sprintf("%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",Today_and_Now())
+            . "|mode:" . $req->param('mode')
+            . "|login:" . $req->param('login')
+            . "|remote_addr:" . $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}
+            . "|$msg\n";
+        print S $logmsg;
```

and :

```
POST request to n-cu.cgi should use parameter "cr_login". If the parameter "login" is passed in a post request, it should throw error and return to login screen.

GET request to n-cu.cgi should use the parameter "login". If the parameter "cr_login" is passed in a post request, it should throw error and return to login screen.
```

so here is how we do it:

- Keep the session cookie and context alive :

  my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new(keep_alive => 10);
     $browser->cookie_jar( {} );
     $browser->agent('Mozilla/8.0');
     #$browser->ssl_opts({ verify_hostname => 0 });
     $browser->show_progress(1);

and later: print the response

```
print "Cookies:\n", Dumper($browser->cookie_jar()), "\n\n";

  my $content =  $response->as_string;
  print "$content\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending password in a cookie? Nope.

Disallow GET for /login.

POST username and password to /login, over SSL.

---

In [CGI](https://metacpan.org/release/CGI), the GET/POST is indicated via the REQUEST_METHOD environment variable.

You cannot stop determined people from issuing a GET request to your server, but you can refuse to process it like so (untested code - you have to fill in details):

```
 if ($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} ne 'POST') {
    # issue a redirect to a suitable error page, then return.        
 }

 my $q = CGI->new();
 my $user = $q->params('username');
 my $password = $q->params('password');

 my $encrypted_password = my_password_encryptor($password);
 unless ( can_log_in($user, $encrypted_password) ) {
   # issue an error message - redirect&return or fall-through...
 }
 else {
   $session->set_user_logged_in();
 }
```

Most people do not roll their own authentication or session handling. They mostly use one from CPAN, or one included with the larger app framework.  If you're doing CGI, you can use CGI::Session.

You might give [CGI::Application](https://metacpan.org/release/CGI-Application) and/or its offspring a look. Those authors have already solved a bunch of the problems that you're encountering.